# Creating an Observable<T> class: overloading = operator?

Tags: c#, wpf, overloading, observable

I'm trying to create a class that holds a value, will raise an event whenever the value changes, and will implicitly convert to and from the type it holds.

My goal is that I should be able to create an Observable property of a class, and have another class (including WPF controls) be able to read and write to it as if it were a regular string.  Other classes could maintain a reference to it as an Observable, or even expose it as its own property without having to create new events.

Here is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SATS.Utilities
{
    public class Observable<T>
    {
        private T mValue;

        public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyValueChanged()
        {
            if (ValueChanged != null)
            {
                ValueChanged(this, new EventArgs());
            }
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return mValue;
            }
            set
            {
                SetValueSilently(value);
                NotifyValueChanged();
            }
        }

        public void SetValueSilently(T value)
        {
            mValue = value;
        }

        public static implicit operator T(Observable<T> observable)
        {
            return observable.Value;
        }

        public static T operator =(Observable<T> observable, T value) // Doesn't compile!
        {
            observable.Value = value;
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the "=" operator is complaining that it cannot be overloaded.  I guess that makes sense, since it could lead to all sorts of strange behaviors.  Is there another way to achieve what I'm going for?

EDIT: Here is how I have decided to implement this.  Let me know if there are any better suggestions :)

I realized that this case should really be handled by the property that holds the Observable.  Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly Observable<string> _property;

    public Observable<string> Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
    }

    public string Property
    {
        set { _property.Value = value; }
    }
}
```

Of course, that doesn't compile because Property is defined twice.  Here's the somewhat hackish workaround that I'm thinking of defining an implicit conversion the other way (as many of you have suggested):

```
public static implicit operator Observable<T>(T value)
{
    var result = new Observable<T>();
    result.SetValueSilently(value);
    return result;
}
```

and using that to call the property's setter:

```
public Observable<string> Property
{
    get { return _property; }
    set { _property.Value = value.Value; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overload the `implicit` operator.

```
public static operator implicit string(YourObject object)
```

and to go the other way

```
public static operator implicit YourObject(string s)
```

Be aware, though, this is *very* dangerous. It can lead to the consumers of the class to do some things you never thought of; and some behavior that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I thought about that, but here's the problem.  Let's say I do the following: [Observable<string> A = new Observable<string>(); Observable<string> B = A; A = "hi";]  Now, A and B are out of sync because instead of setting the value of A, we have replaced it with a new Observable object.

Comment: Actually, I have decided that this will indeed work for me.  I'll edit my question to explain how.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [Overloadable Operators in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you'll see that:

> Assignment operators cannot be overloaded, but +=, for example, is evaluated using +, which can be overloaded.

You can make an `implicit operator Observable<T>(T value)`, however, which would allow you to implicitly convert from `T` to `Observable<T>`.

That being said, I would not recommend this.  I would make the assignment explicit, as this would require creating a *new* `Observable<T>` each time it was called, which is going to cause problems with your event handlers, as each assignment will create a new object instance.

Answer (score 3):

Add another implicit conversion, along these lines:

```
public static implicit operator Observable<T>(T value)
{
    return new Observable<T>{Value = value};
}
```